# javascript localstorage синхронизация полученных сообщений между вкладками браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

К каждой странице сайта прикручен JS файл который с определённым setTimeout делает Ajax запрос к серверу и проверяет на наличие новых сообщений (никаких WebSocket итд не использую, обычный запрос!).

Если сообщение найдено то удаляется сообщение(я) из временной таблицы на сервере и отправляет сообщение клиенту

Возникла проблема... Если в браузере открыто больше одной вкладки то сообщение получает только та вкладка у которой setTimeout сработает первым тк до последующего сообщение уже не доходит поскольку уже было отправлено ранее и удалено, а также из каждой вкладки отправляются запросы которые приводят к лишней нагрузке на сервер.

Есть идея решить данную проблему с применением `javascript localstorage`

Задача отправлять запрос на проверку новых сообщений только из одной вкладки и в случае поступления обновлять данные в соседних вкладках на клиенте.

**ВОПРОСЫ=)**

1) Как отследить состояние вкладки (активна, неактивна, все неактивны)?

2) Какая вкладка должна быть главной для отправки Ajax запроса? (например все вкладки не активны)

3) Возможно есть какое то готовое решение с подробным описанием?

Comment: Записывайте в local storage datetime последнего запроса (при отправки) и его результат (при получении). Перед запросом проверяйте когда был последний по local storage. Если недавно, то запрос не отправляйте, а просто используйте полученный результат. Всё это дело на таймер на каждой вкладке, вроде самый простой вариант

Comment: Есть ещё вариант.. Хоть он и не особо экономны по отношению к интернету юзера. Можно сделать так, чтоб запрос отправлял id последнего полученного сообщения, после чего получал псе сообщения, что есть после этого. Сюда можно приплести и local storage. Пусть js сначала проверят, есть ли в нём сообщения "что после этого"